# Lunar calendar implemenation in android

Tags: android, calendar

I have to implement two calendars in my app **Gregorian** and **Lunar**.I have done with Gregorian but i am stuck on Lunar calendar.

Is there any api available for **Lunar Calendar** implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from this project.
you need to modify to suit your requirements.
code.google.com/p/china-calendar

Comment: Thanks bro but the requested url is not present on server.